# How to disable proration during a subscription update on a product quantity already under use?

Tags: stripe-payments

[image: stripe dashboard reference]
In the above image, I have a subscription already active for 2 seats for 95 usd each.
Now I want to update it to 5 seats but I do not want the in use seats to prorate.
That is, I want the final price to be 285 and not 285.06
How can I achieve this?

I have tried first charging for the extra 3 seats and then setting up a subscription update for the next month for 5 seats which solves this issue but then changes the current subscription to 3 seats.

Comment: Have you tried turning off the "Prorate changes" switch in the upper right of your screenshot?

Comment: @Pompey that will charge for the whole 5 seats. But I want to charge for the added 3 seats.